# How to convert .mp4 to vector animation in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I found this nice tutorial that explains [how to convert a movie file to a .gif in Photoshop](http://www.briandalessandro.com/blog/convert-a-video-file-into-an-animated-gif-with-photoshop/). Is there an analogous process in Illustrator?

Comment: Mp4 and gif are both raster format. Why would you want to go via Illustrator, which is mostly a vector editor?

Comment: @naught101 So that I can make frame-by-frame vector art without first going through Photoshop.

Comment: @naught101 How would you suggest I improve my question? The absence of a feature is difficult to confirm because there's often no documentation explicitly explaining its absence. Scott answered my question perfectly.

Comment: You question doesn't imply that you understand the distinction between raster and vector. Sorry for assuming. Perhaps you should change it to ".mp4 to vector animation", rather than .gif, which is raster-only (you can dump the vector animation to .gif later). Also, including some description of what you want to do with it would be good (i.e. do you want to manually trace each frame of the .mp4?)

Comment: @naught101 I've tried live tracing the video frames, but the results don't achieve the quality that I'm looking for. It looks like I'll have to manually trace the frames and skip frames to save time. Unless you have a better tip? =P

Comment: Blends. Not knowing exactly why you want to use Illustrator for animation (it's really not a great tool for animation, you should use Photoshop or Flash in most cases)..... you may be able to utilize blends to auto-build in-between states of objects.

Comment: @Scott I've tried blends for nonstandard shapes, such as people or shapes with holes, and I've found that the results are hard to predict and control. Are there any good tutorials for blending complex objects?

Comment: I've not seen any direct tutorials. The secret to blends and non-standard shapes is small steps. It's better to blend between 4 objects than it is 2. If you're drawing frames, it may save a step or two, but it most likely won't be the be-all-end-all solution.

Comment: @BBz: search the web for "vector rotoscoping"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Illustrator has no animation set up specifically. There's no structure to interpret existing animation or video within Illustrator.

In fact, the only places Illustrator even remotely addresses any sort of animation is in the ability to build layers in a sequence, and to export to swf format (Flash).

Illustrator can not interpret a video file in any way. Therefore an .mp4 would mean nothing to Illustrator. Illustrator won't even recognize an mp4 file.

Illustrator is also incapable of building gif animations. Even starting from scratch, there is no method to build a timeline or frame animation within Illustrator.

There's nothing you can do with an mp4 in Illustrator and you can not create animated gif files with Illustrator either.

In short... No. There's no analogous processes with Illustrator.